# Can I install Android using Android studio on any supporting devices?

Tags: installation, operating-system, android-studio

I have a Samsung phone. I don't know anything about installing Android and about Android Studio.

Can I install Android on it using Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is purely for developing Android apps. hence you can only build Android apps, install them on a device or emulator and you can run/debug it.

Android Studio has no functionality for flashing Android system images or "installing Android" on a device.

Comment: There is no general Android and no general way to install a new system image onto a device. Nearly every device/chip manufacturer has it's own way to do so. hence without exactly saying what phone model and manufacturer you use nobody can help you. The best way is to visit the device specific forum at https://forum.xda-developers.com/ and read there about the specific way to root your device and install custom ROMs.