# How to use Android sdk to flash android system images

Tags: rom-flashing, android-sdk

Can I use android sdk to flash a system image to a device? If yes, how to do?

Device: Samsung galaxy note3

Model:SM-N9000

Can I install an Android generic system image?.

Comment: Your duplicate question: [Can I install Android using Android studio on any supporting devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225861/can-i-install-android-using-android-studio-on-any-supporting-devices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android SDK contains `fastboot` for flashing images. But Samsung devices are usually not flashable via fastboot.

Instead you need a software named `Odin` or for Linux an "Odin clone" named `Heimdall` exists that can AFAIR also flash firmware images on Samsung devices.

For flashing an "Android generic system image" the current firmware of a device has to be compliant to Googles "Project Treble". There are apps in the Google Play Store that claim to be able to check if a device is "Project Treble" compatible. But I don't have any experience how accurate those apps are.